# rsync: include file from excluded directory

Tags: linux, rsync

So, I'm currently writing my own simple backup-client (based on rsync obviously) and after lots of trial and error I'm left with (hopefully) only one problem.

#### Source folder structure

```
.
├── .hidden_file.txt
├── .hidden_folder
│   └── .keep
├── regular_file.txt
└── regular_folder
    └── .keep
```

#### Backup command

As you can see, I'm trying to "simply" exclude eveything that matches `regular*` **but** explicitly include the file `.keep` within the `regular_folder` folder.
That's the idea at least.

```
rsync --archive --relative --prune-empty-dirs <many other options> \
      --include='/data/source/regular_folder/.keep' \
      --exclude='regular*' \
      /data/source /data/target/<timestamp>
```

#### What I want

```
.
├── .hidden_file.txt
└── .hidden_folder
    └── .keep
└── regular_folder
    └── .keep
```

#### What I actually get

```
.
├── .hidden_file.txt
└── .hidden_folder
    └── .keep
```

I obviously did my fair share of googeling, man-page reading but either something obvious must have slipped me or... I don't know.

I understand that in my scenario I'd have to additionally `--include='/data/source/regular_folder/` (the parent directory of the file I want) **but** if there'd be other files alongside `.keep`, those would automatically be included as well which I **do not** want.

Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it :)

#### Update

**Edit**
Ignore all that. With my new test-cases it doesn't work anymore (which makes sense as excludes should always be prior to sources. No idea why it worked with my initial tests). Back to the drawing-board :/

**Original**
After playing with my unittests following what *ams* proposed (which sadly didn't work out the way I wanted it to) I thought of something else.

Instead of adding the files/folders I explicitly want via `--include`, I can just add them as additional *sources* to rsync.
The new command would look like this:

```
rsync --archive --relative --prune-empty-dirs <many other options> \
      --exclude='regular*' \
      /data/source /data/source/regular_folder/.keep' \
      /data/target/<timestamp>
```

This works nicely but...

...you guessed it, there's another problem. Source don't really work with wildcards when they would have to descend into directories.
Say I want to keep all `.keep` files, I would like to:

```
rsync --archive --relative --prune-empty-dirs <many other options> \
      --exclude='regular*' \
      /data/source /data/source/*/.keep' \
      /data/target/<timestamp>
```

Multiple `*` didn't work either.

The question now. Am I just to stupid to get this to work or is that impossible?

I know sources work with wildcards within a flat hierarchy.
For example the following would work as source:

```
/some/path/*.txt
```

Comment: Have you consider issuing 2 commands, where the second is just for the .keep file?

Comment: Yeah, thought about that but don't really like it as rsync can handle includes/excludes. So there gotta be a way to get it working with only one command :)

Comment: Well good luck, I'm sure that there is an answer. One thing to bear in mind, is that in the future your requirements will change and when they change, bending your custom command will rear its complicated head again. Sometimes simple is best.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
--include='/data/source/regular_folder/.keep'
--exclude='regular*/**'
```

Basically, that excludes all the files inside `regular_folder`, but not the folder itself.

It does exclude subdirectories though, so `.keep` files at deeper levels are not going to work. If you have that then something like this ought to work:

```
--include='/data/source/regular_folder/.keep'
--include='/data/source/regular_folder/deeper/deeper/.keep'
--include='*/'
--exclude='regular*/**'
```

Or, to simply include *all* `.keep` files:

```
--include='.keep'
--include='*/'
--exclude='regular*/**'
```

The `'*/'` means "include all directories", but doesn't say anything about the files.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Will give that a try tomorrow and report back :)
If that works, it's just a matter of properly configuring the paths/patterns within my clients UI (will need proper documentation at that point *sigh* :D)